# (OpenGL) How to transform an object while keeping an identical object stationary?

Tags: c++, opengl, syntax, logic

So I had a quick question about a homework assignment I was assigned for my OpenGL class. In class, we made two triangles transform (get bigger and smaller) as they follow a sine wave, and our homework is to make it so that only one transforms while the other stays static, all while only using one vertex shader, one fragment shader, and uniform variables. When I tried it, my mindset was to somehow return the value of 1 to a Scale variable to keep one of the triangles from moving. I was able to make it so that one of the triangles was stationary, but no shader was attached to it, so it was solid white. I have a feeling I have to use some OOP to create another instance of the triangle, but I really can't wrap my head around how I'm supposed to distinguish between the two triangles while only using one vertex shader. Can anyone shed some light onto this? This is the hardest class of the curriculum, so even a hint would be lovely! Thank you! I can post my code if you all want, but I made some changes to it that made my program cry, so I'll try to retrace my steps and post it tomorrow! Thank you all!

[EDIT] Okay here's my code. Trying to make it so that only the red triangle is static. I have a feeling the answer is in the provided class in the form of an "if statement", though I could be wrong about the complexity of this problem. Thank you all again for helping me.

```
    #include "Triangle.h"



Triangle::Triangle(vec3 points[], vec4 color[], GLuint pID)
{
ProgramID = pID;

memcpy(Points, points, sizeof(Points));
memcpy(Colors, color, sizeof(Colors));

glUseProgram(ProgramID);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VBO);
glBindVertexArray(VBO);

glGenBuffers(1, &VB);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VB);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Points), Points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));


glGenBuffers(1, &CB);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CB);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Colors), Colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


Scale = 90.0f;
gScaleLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramID, "Scale");

}


void Triangle::Draw()
{
glUseProgram(ProgramID);
glBindVertexArray(VBO);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
if ()
{
    Scale += 0.0f;
}
else
{
    Scale += 0.01f;
}

glUniform1f(gScaleLocation, sinf(Scale));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);



}
```

Comment: Are you drawing the triangles separately? Do you have one draw command or two?

Comment: If the triangles are moved by the vertex or fragment shader entirely, simply pass a uniform to distinguish between the to different triangles. You can then use it to "if-out" the movement for the static version or simply pass an identity matrix for the transformation. In any case: show some code!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting the animation logic into the `Triangle` class, move it to the caller. So first extract the scaling factor as a parameter:

```
void Triangle::Draw(double scale)
{
    glUseProgram(ProgramID);
    glBindVertexArray(VBO);
    glUniform1f(gScaleLocation, scale);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

Next call `Draw` with different parameters on different triangle instances:

```
// your triangles. I assume you have two instances based on the little code you provided.
Triangle tri0, tri1;

// add this to some context, initialized to 0
int frame;

// Your rendering function, you didn't post it.
void render()
{
    tri0.Draw(1); // triangle 0 is not animating
    tri1.Draw(sin(frame*0.01)); // triangle 1 follows a sine wave
    frame++;
}
```

Comment: So not only is the sine wave established in the same class as the triangles, but our professor gave us some code to work off of, and he uses an iterator to draw the triangles. It looks a little like this: void display()
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

 for (vector<Triangle>::iterator it = triangles.begin(); it != triangles.end(); ++it) {
  it->Draw();
 }
 glutSwapBuffers();
}                                                                                                                     How would I do what you said, but through an iterator, as I'm not familiar with them. Thanks!